# Uniform sampling of convex polytopes: why is it hard?

Tags: geometry, sampling, convex-geometry

There is a surprising number of posts asking about the uniform sampling of convex polytopes (e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343240/51744), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9854/60498), [3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3227/80744)), and an equally surprising number of non-answers (e.g. [a](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9858/60498), [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343674/51744)).

From what I have read, this seems to be a difficult problem; and known solutions consist in partitioning the polytope into a collection of simplices, select one randomly, and sample a uniformly random point from it. That is assuming that we know the vertices of the polytope in the first place (otherwise the problem is [apparently NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem)?).

From what I know, sampling uniformly random points from a d-dimensional simplex with d+1 known vertices is done in two steps:

1. Sample d+1 weights from a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function) with parameters $(\alpha_k = 1)_{k=0..d}$
2. Compute the corresponding weighted sum of vertices

Assuming this is correct, my question is: **why can we not apply the same method to sample any convex polytope uniformly randomly?** I.e. by computing a weighted sum of its vertices, with weights sampled from a Dirichlet distribution.

Is it because it has not been proven that this would result in a uniform distribution, or because there are known cases where it does not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it seems the short answer is: "because it doesn't work".

It is still unclear to me why that is; and I should probably first try to understand why it works in the case of a simplex. But trying the same method on regular polygons yields a sampling density that is not uniform:

[image: Sampling density using Dirichlet weights]

Comment: Intuitively, I suppose this has to do with intersections. Take e.g. the pentagon, and label the vertices 1 to 5 in adjacent order. Draw a line from 1 to 3 and one from 2 to 4. The intersection is a point that you can express with at least two different Dirichlet samples. However, a point on the line from 1 to 2 is only expressible by one sample. This is not a problem in the simplex.

Comment: @cangrejo That's a nice way of looking at it! And it almost seems like there should be a way to "correct" for such duplicate combinations _a posteriori_, without having to partition the polytope with simplices... But I am sure this is more difficult than it seems as well :)

Comment: This picture is really worth a thousand words.